# load image on canvas when navigate.. which is on other canvas in other page with c# and xaml in windows app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

**I have used the following code to pick image on a canvas.Now I want add this image on another canvas which is on different page when am navigate to it.**

```
private async void edit_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker filepicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        filepicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        filepicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        filepicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile imageFile = await filepicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (imageFile != null)
        {
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmap = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            Image newImage = new Image();
            bitmap.SetSource(stream);
            newImage.Source = bitmap;
            newImage.Height = 250;
            newImage.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
            newImage.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;

            this.theCanvas.Children.Add(newImage);
        }
    }

    private void save_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(showdp));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in many ways, one is create a static repository of images like:

```
public class Settings
{
 public static Image CanvasImage;
}
```

And set that in your code, in edit click or where you consider, and you can get and set from any part of the app using:

```
Settings.CanvasImage = ...
```